# Images does not show immediately after ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using an Ajax for partial loading my website. Content of GET data has images but these images appear after few seconds on page. Image size is about 20kB, so this is not a bottleneck.

I'm using php page which returns some content. This page loads in a while with images immediately but with ajax it loads text, but images after few seconds. How can I achieve quick load?

I'm using this function:

```
function loadMainEvents(resultDiv, cat, limit){
  var spinner = new Spinner().spin(mainPageEvents);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/getMainPageEvents.php?category=" + cat + "&limit=" + limit,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        resultDiv.innerHTML = data;        
        spinner.stop();
    }
  }); 
};
```

EDIT:
I created a test.php which is doing same thing

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div" style="float:left;">wait</div>
    <div id="div2">wait</div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/getMainPageEvents.php?category=&limit=10&from=29.11.2015&to=29.11.2015&pno=1",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#div").html(data).on('load', function () {
                        $(this).fadeIn(250);
                    });
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/getMainPageEvents.php?category=&limit=10&from=29.11.2015&to=29.11.2015&pno=1",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#div2").html(data).on('load', function () {
                        $(this).fadeIn(250);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

getMainPageEvents.php returns only web content.

Network from developer tools:

[image: Developer tools Network]

Comment: how does data look like ?

Comment: it is part of html page -> divs, imgs, spans...

Comment: AFAIU the browser is loading the images and network requests take time, you can try base64 encoding the image and send it as text but its not really a good solution :/

Comment: I tried sending only url of an image by json, and whole image too, both was same result. As I said, when I try call the url in browser, it loads in few seconds, but somehow when I use AJAX, images are loaded with delay... I don't understand that.

Comment: I found a problem. I'm using NetBeans for development and if I run my project with it, images load up slow... But if I run my project via XAMPP, it works like a charm. The thing is that my netbeans uses its build-in web server, although php interpreter is set as my XAMPPdir/php.exe. Does anybody know, what is wrong with NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something like this in the success function. Hide the result div first and foremost, then after the data is loaded, show the div.

```
$(resultDiv).html(data).promise().done(function(){
    spinner.stop();
    $(this).fadeIn(250);        
});
```

Possible second solution

```
$(resultDiv).html(data).on('load', function(){
    spinner.stop();
    $(this).fadeIn(250);        
});
```

Comment: If I use this, it works like my solution - loads content and in chrome developer tools network tab is next to image row "pending" - it take few seconds to load it.

Comment: Ahhh...that's a bummer. I will add another possible solution.

Comment: Ok, I found that if I call only one ajax function of my four functions, images loads immediately after ajax content loads, BUT if I call two functions with ajax, images from first function appears right after second ajax function completed... WHY?

Comment: @JayDee I'm not entirely sure. The calls are asynchronous so I would think they are independent of each other. You may need to to look into added methods of the ajax call such as .promise() , .then() , .done() ...and possibly chain the ajax calls where they are queued and each one only runs after the previous one completes.

Comment: I added new info with network, I'm calling twice the same url, but all images still load after second ajax ends...

Comment: When I use your first solution it trims the data. In data I have list of events with pagination, events will show, but pagination is trimmed, so innerHTML on the element is the best choise for me...

Comment: Hmm, that's wierd... `$.html()` is the equivilant to JS `.innerHTML = " ";`